# httpd mod_mime configuration and Browser not displaying images

Tags: php, css, apache, clearos

I am just a college student who is working on a task involvong installing a server OS for web hosting and security testing. The OS I'm assigned to is ClearOS 6 Community Edition.

I am facing a bit of a problem with AddType in Apache web server on my ClearOS 6.

The thing is, I am trying to host a website for local testing. When I hosted it, it displayed all the images that I linked on the php homepage file, but it didn't apply the css file.

When I add the ifModule (AddType text/css .css) line for enabling .css file extensions, it did apply the css,but this time, all the images no longer show.

I have erased the line and restarted Apache, but it's still stuck on the images not showing...

[after AddType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SatT.png)

I am sorry I couldn't provide you with the one before AddType since the webpage is now stuck at that whatever I tried...

Could someone please help me with this? Any suggestions would be appreciated. If you need anything please let me know, I'll try to provide you with that. :D